# Como alinhar o botão fechar da janela pop-up?

Tags: css

Estou criando uma janela pop-up em `CSS`, porém o botão para fechar não fica dentro do elemento onde exibe a propaganda na pop-up. O botão fica no canto extremo esquerdo do site.

Observe abaixo minha pop-up, está certa. Porém, veja no canto superior esquerdo do site o (X) para fechar a propaganda pop-up.

Como fazer o botão fechar ficar localizado na quina superior direita da pop-up?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<figure class="pop-up-principal">
    <span id="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="./imagens-pop-up/drbrunomachado.jpg">
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure.pop-up-principal img{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 378px;
    max-height: 283px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #9AD3DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#close{
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #EF5350;
  border:2px solid #EF9A9A;
}
```

Comment: você está utilizando Bootstrap ?

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman não! Apenas Css.

Comment: Talvez este [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9qoma1b/3/) te ajude a chegar no resultado esperado.

Comment: @Gladison aconselho você a usar o Bootstrap modal, mais simples e eficiente, eis um exemplo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery

Comment: @MathiasFalci prefiro ajustar este código que utilizo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte, você de tirar o position fixed, pois ele não se comporta bem com base em containeres, todas as propriedades que você colocou na imagem deveriam ser aplicadas no container, pois a imagem somente deve ser redimencionada com base no mesmo, com alguns ajustes, pode-se obter o resultado esperado...

> Edit: Você queria uma solução responsiva também. segue o código

--

```css
figure.pop-up-principal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 430px;
    max-height: 283px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
figure.pop-up-principal img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 430px;
    max-height: 283px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #9AD3DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#close{
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  border:2px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="pop-up-principal">
    <span id="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/07/27/13/49/tree-402953__340.jpg">
</figure>
```

Comment: A imagem está saindo do espaço delimitando, como deixá-la dentro do espaço delimitado pela margem?

Comment: adicione 'overflow: hidden;' em 'figure.pop-up-principal'

Comment: Este seu código não funcionou! Ao incluí-lo, algumas estruturas CSS do restante do site ficaram desconfiguradas.

Comment: deve ser pela tag img no css, adicione uma classe para a imagem central do modal e chame a mesma pelo css

Comment: A imagem não está ajustada para trabalhar o redimensionamento junto com figure

Comment: ai já não entendi nada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62719/discussion-between-gladison-and-felipe-duarte).

Answer (score 0):

```css
figure.pop-up-principal img{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 378px;
    max-height: 283px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #9AD3DE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#close{
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #EF5350;
  right: 0; 
  border:2px solid #EF9A9A;
    z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

```html
<figure class="pop-up-principal">
    <span id="close">X</span>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg">
</figure>
```

É isso que você precisa?